# macOS Sierra CSS general sibling combinator - weird behaviour

Tags: css, macos, tilde

This snippet with 'spaces' around the tilde does not work.

```css
  h3 ~ p {
   color: red;
  }
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
 <title></title>

</head>
<body>
<h3>this does not work</h3>
<p>sibling</p>
<p>sibling</p>
<p>sibling</p>
</body>
</html>
```

This snippet without the spaces does work.

```css
  h3~p {
   color: red;
  }
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
 <title></title>

</head>
<body>
<h3>this does work</h3>
<p>sibling</p>
<p>sibling</p>
<p>sibling</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Undo will revert to not working whereas when I put 'new' blank spaces around the tilde it works.

```css
  h3 ~ p {
   color: red;
  }
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
 <title></title>

</head>
<body>
<h3>this does work</h3>
<p>sibling</p>
<p>sibling</p>
<p>sibling</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Since CSS in general has the power to make me want to tear my hair out it would be nice if someone could help me avoid these kinds of problems.

Comment: Are you using VSCode, Atom, Sublime or a similar IDE meant for development? Since you think this is potentially related to your operating system, it could be macOS putting invalid characters in your document if you're using Apple TextEdit or something like that.

Comment: It's the same whether I use Sublime Text or Textmate or vim. That's why I think it has to do with the OS.

Comment: Can you reproduce the issue in a Stack Overflow snippet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you have a non-breaking space right after the tilde in your first example. It appears if you accidentally press `option+space` instead of `space`.

[Read more here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/34672/whats-altspacebar-character-and-how-to-disable-it)

The errors like this is a real headache sometimes!

Comment: Wow. Thanks. I'm on a german keyboard, ~ = option+n. The solution to this is in the link above but here it is anyway: Create ~/Library/KeyBindings/DefaultKeyBinding.dict if that does not already exist and type: {
"~ " = ("insertText:", " ");
} This will prevent non-breaking space ( NBSP ) after the tilde.

Comment: @fx____, happy to help!